# Volume to surface integral of $R\times \nabla \times B$

Tags: integration, surface-integrals, cross-product, stokes-theorem, curl

I need to transform the following integral into a surface integral (if that's possible):
$$\int\int\int_\Omega R\times (\nabla \times A) dv = \int\int_{\partial \Omega} ? . {\bf n} da, $$
where $R = (x,y,z)$. Any idea?

Comment: You can use $\vec a\times(\vec b\times\vec c)=(\vec a\cdot\vec c)\vec b-(\vec a\cdot\vec b)\vec c$.

Comment: thx, but I failed with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer:

First, we know from our vector calculus identities that
$$
\mathbf{r}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{A}) = \nabla(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{A}) - \mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla\mathbf A - \mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{A}\times(\nabla\times \mathbf{r}) = \nabla(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{A}) - \mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla\mathbf A - \mathbf{A},
$$
where we have used $\nabla\times\mathbf{r} = 0$ and $\nabla \mathbf{r} = I$. Now, we can mostly put this into divergence form using $\nabla\cdot (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{r}) = \mathbf{A}\nabla\cdot \mathbf{r} + \mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{A} = 3\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{A}$ and $\nabla f = \nabla\cdot(fI)$, giving
$$
\mathbf{r}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{A}) = \nabla \cdot[(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{A})I - \mathbf{A}\mathbf{r}] + 2\mathbf{A}.
$$
Now we can apply the divergence theorem to get
$$
\iiint_\Omega\mathbf{r}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{A})dV = \iint_{\partial \Omega}\left[(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{A})\hat{n} - (\mathbf{r}\cdot\hat{n})\mathbf{A}\right]dS + 2\iiint_\Omega\mathbf{A}dV \\= \iint_{\partial \Omega}\left[\mathbf{r}\times(\hat{n}\times\mathbf{A})\right]dS + 2\iiint_\Omega\mathbf{A}dV
$$
Unfortunately I'm not sure if there's a sneaky way to write $\mathbf{A}$ as the divergence of some tensor $\mathbf{T}$ that depends on $\mathbf{A}$ in a simple way. But it certainly makes the volume integral simpler.